# Count dead enemies in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm programming a racing game. 
You can wreck your opponents and I want to count the enemies you've wrecked.
I do this in this way:

```cs
if(Wrecked){
    Smoke.Emit();
    EngineTorque = 0;
    PlayerCar_Script.EnemyWrecked += 1;
}
```

I think you can see my issue. It will not count just 1 up it will count endless ....
How can I fix this ? I also tried SendMessage, but it ends up in the same issue :/

Comment: I'm guessing from your question that you're running the above code in an `Update` or `FixedUpdate` method?

Answer (score 2):

> It will not count just 1 up it will count endless

that sounds like you're running the above code repeatedly, but not setting PlayerCar_Script.EnemyWrecked back to 0 between each run.  I'm guessing you have this in the car's monobehavior.update() function.  Instead, only increment EnemyWrecked when you change from not wrecked to wrecked.

Use a variable for each wreckable car to determine if it was wrecked the last time you checked.

```c#
bool wasWreckedLastFrame = false;
```

and then change your above code segment to this:

```c#
if(Wrecked && wasWreckedLastFrame==false){
    wasWreckedLastFrame = true;
    Smoke.Emit();
    EngineTorque = 0;
    PlayerCar_Script.EnemyWrecked += 1;
}
```